# detecting black squares over white board matlab using a webcam

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I am a student just learning about matlab, im using the version R2014a student.

I need to use a webcam to detect 3 squares (2cm x 2 cm each one) that will be randomly colocated. I must have the position and it's centroid for each of the 3 squares, I must have the position and orientation (the relative angle to the x axis of the image) and I should ve able to constantly detect them.
The webcam is set to a fixed position, and I need to know which is the distance I've got from each square to it's relative position at the board.

The code I have so far is the following: (currently I am not able to detect them properly and I cannot know the distance)

```
vid=videoinput('winvideo', 1)
preview(vid)
constantlydoing =1
while constantlydoing>=1
%Sacar fotografía del tablero (obtain a photo of the board)
image=getsnapshot(vid);
imshow(image)


%Conversión BW
level = graythresh(image);
imageBW = im2bw(image,level);
imageBW= not (imageBW);
imshow(imageBW);
L = bwlabel(imageBW,8);
imshow(L);
pause(1);
s=regionprops(L, 'centroid');
centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);
j=regionprops(L, 'Perimeter');
k=regionprops(L, 'orientation');
orientations = cat(1, k.Orientation);


%determinamos perímetro (perimeter detect)
perimetro = cat(1, j.Perimeter);
[m,n]= size(perimetro);
pos=find(perimetro(:,1)>=100);
centroids=[centroids(pos(1),1) centroids(pos(1),2);...
       centroids(pos(2),1) centroids(pos(2),2);...
       centroids(pos(3),1) centroids(pos(3),2)];
%orientacion (orientation)

orientations=[orientations(pos(1),1);...
       orientations(pos(2),1) ;...
       orientations(pos(3),1)]

%Localización de los cubos (localization of squares)
cubo1=centroids(1,1:2);
cubo2=centroids(2,1:2);
cubo3=centroids(3,1:2);      
hold on; 
plot(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2),'b*');
hold off;
propied=regionprops(L,'BoundingBox');
hold on

% Plot Bounding Box
for n=1:size(propied,1)
rectangle('Position',propied(n).BoundingBox ...
,'EdgeColor','g','LineWidth',2); ...
end
hold off
pause(1);
end
```

Comment: Could you provide the error you get? I am thinking maybe your threshold is not good for your application. What exactly is your problem? Could you provide a sample of your image after conversion to binary?

Comment: Please step through your code in the Matlab debugger and try to narrow down the part where the error happens.  Questions with this much code and no explanation beyond "It doesn't work" are like asking other users to do your job for you.

Comment: the error is that sometimes the program is not detecting that there are squares, although they are psysically there. Also I do not know how to give the meassurement of the pixels in longitude

Comment: @japreiss as I said, I am unable to finish what I intend to, I need help developing my code, and the error is that sometimes it says:that tthere are no variables for the position

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use the debugger, it is helpful for figuring out why your code isn't working.  You can step through your code a single line at a time, look at the value of all your variables at each step, and even execute code from the command line while your program is paused.  Debuggers are very powerful. [Here is a good tutorial video on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLS6A8shLJw)